# ${#array} vs ${#array[@]}

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zsh, array

As far as I can tell both `${#array[@]}` and `${#array}` evaluate to the number of elements in `$array`.  Is there any reason for preferring the longer form (`${#array[@]}`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In zsh, personal preference. In other shells `$array` may only expand to the first element, thus `${#array}` would output the length of the first element.

So, if you want to be little more portable between shells specifying the `[@]` would work.

In zsh, `$array` expands in the same way `$array[*]` would, which differs depending on if they appear within quotes or not. Should they appear within double quotes `"$array"` would expand and be delimited by the first character of `IFS` which by default is space

```
zsh% touch {1..10}; a=(*)
zsh% printf '<%s> ' $a
<1> <10> <2> <3> <4> <5> <6> <7> <8> <9>     
zsh% printf '<%s> ' "$a"
<1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9> 
zsh% IFS=:
zsh% print "$a"
1:10:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9
zsh% print "$a[@]"
1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
zsh% IFS=$' \t\n'
zsh% rm "$a"
rm: cannot remove ‘1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9’: No such file or directory
```

Changing `IFS` is rarely needed which prompted my original "Personal preferences" response. But just to clarify there is a few differences between the two when used without the `#` flag, they are is just very subtle.

I prefer `$array[@]` also since it's behavior doesn't change depending on whether or not it appears within quotes. That and internal whitespace that an element may have is preserved.

Comment: Added more details you may want to be aware of.

Answer (score 4):

As with anything, the more readable and understandable your code the easier it is for others (or future you) to maintain. When you have a choice and one of them is ambiguous, choose the other.

Additionally, if you want portability in your shell scripts, the latter is the only one that works properly in `bash`.

Comment: Well, that's what I saw yesterday but I didn't keep my notes and I can't reproduce it so there was something wrong with my example. I've removed that portion of my answer. But the question is about `${#array[@]}`, not `${#array[0]}`. Even with your example, if `${#array}` and `${#array[@]}` were the same you would get `5 5` on line 4, not `3 5` since the expectation is both forms count the elements of the array. In `zsh` they are equivalent, in `bash` they are not.

Answer (score 4):

In most shells that support arrays (I've tested it in `bash`, `ksh93` and `pdksh`), `${#array}` will give the length of `${array[0]}`, and `${#array[@]}` will give the number of elements in the array. This is logical:  `"${array}"` returns element `0` of the array and `"${#array}"` returns its length.